# Format HD using disk utility

Tags: partitioning

I have a new hard drive that I will use only for storing data.

I am following the instructions from: http://www.ubuntulinuxguide.com/ubuntu-1204-lts/hard-disk-partition -  but I can't find this window! [image]

My problem right now is that I seem to have 3 partitions! [image]

I want to format the whole damn thing and make it just one partition (with filesystem NTFS) for private data. 
When I try to format or delete the disk, it formats/deletes every partition individually - instead of merging everything and cleaning out the entire disk. What am I doing wrong?